# Why doesn't unwrapping and re-wrapping an array of types give me back the original type?

Tags: typescript

My `UnwrapArray<T>` type gives me `T` from `Array<T>`. So when I do `Array<UnwrapArray<T>>`, that's supposed to resolve to just `T`, however that doesn't happen.

The error message is telling me literally the opposite of this definition:

> Type 'UnwrapArray[]' is not assignable to type 'T'.

Here's a full example:

```
type UnwrapArray<T> = T extends Array<infer V> ? V : never
type SomeStructure<T> = { foo: T }

class Foo<T extends Array<any>> {

    prop!: T

    structs!: Array<SomeStructure<UnwrapArray<T>>>

    setProp () {
        this.prop = this.structs.map(x => x.foo)
    }

}
```

[**Playground** link is over here.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgdwE4EMwEEmpAHgCoB8UAvFHlBAB7ARwAmAzlJtjgJZwBmESUAakQD8-KAC4ocCADceAKFCQoAZQD2AWwhLgSAK4BjYDqQR8RUgG8onFSvHkAvrNl6ANigZMAYjfwVqtRmYsFFwUOBACInMnKFioMCQVMABCOxi4hm19YAZUoNZVDS1dAyMTeGQ0FhDTSPTYhghgAAVEsCgACgBKKGi4-qhgAAs2BgA6BKSSQZHxzJKcsbU0DsoSIkox6xUu2X7HWUcgA)

The error is observable in the assignment inside `setProp` method.

I am looking for both an explanation on why this doesn't work, and for instructions on how should I change types in order to get the intended behavior to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want `T` to  be a subtype of `any[]`.  There are lots of subtypes of `any[]` that will violate the assumptions you have about what `setProp()` will do.  The simplest example I can think of is a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple), as in the following example:

```
const foo = new Foo<[1, "a"]>();
```

Note that `foo` has specified `T` as the tuple `[1, "a"]`.  That means `foo.prop` must be an array of exactly two elements, the first of which is `1` and the second of which is `"a"`.  However, the type of `foo.structs`, as defined by your unwrap/modify/wrap definition, is `Array<{foo: 1 | "a"}>`.  So the following assignment is valid:

```
foo.structs = [{ foo: "a" }, { foo: 1 }, { foo: "a" }]; // Array<{foo: 1 | "a"}>;
```

Then we call `setProp()`, and examine `prop`:

```
foo.setProp();
console.log(foo.prop); // [1, "a"] at compile time, ["a", 1, "a"] at runtime
```

Oops, the type of `foo.prop` is supposedly `[1, "a"]`, but the value at runtime is `["a", 1, "a"]`.  That's bad, and the error was in the line `this.prop = this.structs.map(x => x.foo)`.

The error message:

```
'UnwrapArray<T>[]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'any[]'.
```

is the compiler saying that it knows that `UnwrapArray<T>[]` is assignable to `any[]`, but that `T` might be some other subtype of `any[]` to which `UnwrapArray<T>[]` cannot be assigned... and that's exactly what happens when `T` is, for example, a tuple type.

---

From here it is possible (but not necessarily advisable) to go down the route of using [mapped arrays/tuples](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) to represent the type of `structs`, such as:

```
structs!: { [K in keyof T]: { foo: T[K] } }
```

This will prevent the erroneous defining of `foo.structs` from earlier

```
const foo = new Foo<[1, "a"]>();
foo.structs = [{ foo: "a" }, { foo: 1 }, { foo: "a" }]; // error, as desired
```

which is safer.  In fact I think this might be completely type safe now.  Unfortunately the compiler still can't verify that inside `setProp()`:

```
setProp() {
  this.prop = this.structs.map(x => x.foo); // still error
}
```

The problem here is that the standard library typing for `Array.prototype.map()` is not equipped to deal with mapped array/tuple types, and if you try to write typings that do, you'll find that the compiler will not easily be convinced that `x => x.foo` will map `typeof this.structs` to `T`. You might as well skip all the higher-order type juggling here and use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), once you've convinced yourself that it really is safe (or at least safe enough in practice):

```
this.prop = this.structs.map(x => x.foo) as T;
```

---

But I take it you don't really intend for `T` to be an *extension* of `any[]`.  It's more like you want `T` to be exactly `Array<V>` for some element type `V`.  In which case we should just make that element our generic type instead:

```
class Foo<T> {
  prop!: T[];

  structs!: { foo: T }[];

  setProp() {
    this.prop = this.structs.map(x => x.foo); // okay
  }
}

const foo = new Foo<1 | "a">();
foo.structs = [{ foo: "a" }, { foo: 1 }, { foo: "a" }]; // Array<{foo: 1 | "a"}>;

foo.setProp();
console.log(foo.prop); // Array<1 | "a"> at compile time, which matches ["a", 1, "a"] at runtime
```

That now works with no errors, and is pretty straightforward because the types are simpler.  `foo.prop` is of type `Array<1 | "a">`, and `foo.structs` is of type `Array<{foo: 1 | "a"}>`, and `map()` works just fine to convert one to the other.  So this is the way I'd suggest you proceed unless your use case requires that the generic parameter itself be some array type.

---

Okay, hope one of those helped.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOYGED2AJsgN4BQSSALgJ4zICqwA7miDAIJqvUA8AKgD4kAXiR8kEAB6UIwAlCSduPDMABmENEgBqQgPw6kALiTAIAN00BuclVrIAynkgPKaAK7xK7tBH5DRYiQ1PDwTcQBfG1t4ABsQKAUAMVD+CWlZeUUuEF4QYGoBITIKChg0PBgAQnDo0qQoN09KKBrs5ScXJq8fP0YWNiVc-yK60qgISgAFCpgACgBKJBL6qgALDCgAOnLKkXXNrcaPL22wNjnJESFJLZC8BaskAHpniS48NCrbCgjbP5ieGAjWCoX2ZiYSBSeB4AG0AIwAGiQACIQCiALoCRY2Cj3I7dFr7WFBe4mNEopARZGk0ImeFUmmgsKo9FUjFPV7tYbEMlIBkAH1ZKIiAjG+Im01mOMBwLwsQgW1ieCwc3xuxgjxebwRyIpGKQIEoSHgzhgGAVVAwkCQACN3MbYRTkUjhQajUgPMBKNaIKQAaBILAEMh2IlND6gcsYvFElDUuIpDI5AohnkCkVo-UNW0+GMKMdmq0TEFYQBpJCqJAAawg1DwajEGJLzPC5YNESp+YakxmlUWWdWlA22w1+2Hh0Lpy253mV2ENzuoSWCTEuNKf1+pFlIPu4IgkOhcNd+uxj1sEsJClEJNbwsZyzvDOpj75FPZnLemgqX3928D0BwIgSAONaMCxBgajUAAksaKxxAkyQJsUPxIDmbYctu9RTi0bS0iykSwphqGSn28xLCs9QTqOszjiOBInC0M4XPOi73Oe9SblSWEmkCu5gqIELxjCgrCme66Xox15ILeb5si++H0g+in3hEHLatyvC8nS-JIEKFKiuKoRHL20ocbxcoKkqKpqsZGpalyaY8KJFJCB6ppgOalo+pAyJMBs8BrEg5yUIF0Ayc6-J6ui7rGl6Pl+n8QA)

Comment: This makes sense. The example was taken out of context where I needed `T` to already be an array (which is why it looks weird in this case). Thanks for the detailed explanation, now I know why it won't work. :)